# How do I redirect to a new component after form onSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm doing Wes-Bos tutorial and thinking about another way to redirect to App.js component after the form is submitted from StorePicker.

My StorePicker component:

```
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
  goToStore(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
    return <Redirect to={`/store/${storeId}`} />;
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Grid textAlign='center' columns={2}>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column><br/>
            <Segment>
              <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.goToStore(e)} >
                <Form.Field >
                  <h1>Store Name</h1>
                  <input type="text" required
                    placeholder="Store Name"
                    ref={(input) => {this.storeInput = input}}
                    defaultValue={getFunName()} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button fluid type='submit'>Visit Store -></Button>
              </Form>
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm looking through React router documentation and trying to play around with it's `<Redirect />` doesn't seem to work. Any advice how to manage this redirection? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code where you use the `storeId` param to render the selected store (presumably through a `<Store>` component)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what u asking but my `const storeId = this.storeInput.value;` is defined in `goToStore();`

Comment: No, I meant the component that `/store/:storeId` routes to, and where, obviously, you make use of the `storeId` param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) prop programmatically:

> push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack

```
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
  goToStore = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push(`/store/${this.storeInput.value}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid textAlign="center" columns={2}>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column>
            <br />
            <Segment>
              <Form onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
                <Form.Field>
                  <h1>Store Name</h1>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    required
                    placeholder="Store Name"
                    ref={(input) => {
                      this.storeInput = input;
                    }}
                    defaultValue={getFunName()}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button fluid type="submit">
                  Visit Store ->
                </Button>
              </Form>
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

There's also replace if you don't want to create an item in the history.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've manage to make it work looking through some other examples. My working code is below. It looks a bit complicated.

Is there a better way doing it?

```
class StorePicker extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      fireRedirect: false
    }
  }
  goToStore(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ fireRedirect: true })

  }

  render () {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || '/'
    const { fireRedirect } = this.state

    return (
      <Grid textAlign='center' columns={2}>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column><br/>
            <Segment>
              <Form onSubmit={(e) => this.goToStore(e)} >
                <Form.Field >
                  <h1>Store Name</h1>
                  <input type="text" required
                    placeholder="Store Name"
                    ref={(input) => {this.storeInput = input}}
                    defaultValue={getFunName()} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button fluid type='submit'>Visit Store -></Button>
              </Form>
              {fireRedirect && (
                <Redirect to={from || `/store/${this.storeInput.value}`}/>)}
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```